# mysql won't start for xampp for mac users

Tags: mysql, xampp, config

======

Mysql cannot start, i am thinking maybe it was conflict with other mysql i have install in my computer.

How to properly config mysql?

I have tried to kill the mysql task, or sudo start it in my terminal

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked for me, assuming you are using Yosemite:

Step 1.

```
Delete \Applications\Xampp
```

Step 2.

```
Delete usr\local\var\mysql folder
```

Step 3.

Reinstall Xampp 5.5.19.

Step 4. Run the following commands in terminal to kill the processes, then restart the servers in Xampp.

```
sudo killall httpd 
sudo killall mysqld
```